# Google translated pages - links not working

Tags: html, google-translate

a client of mine wanted a website translated in some languages. We decided to use the simple Google Translate funcion.

The issue is that everytime the website is translated the majority of the links aren't working anymore (you can't click on them).

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got into the same trouble. The problem came from jQuery scripts conflicts in my case.

If you manage to deal with all script errors / conflicts on both the Google translated and the original pages of your website, you'll be fine - all the links should work.

Other situation that can occur is that you create an HTML structure with block elements inside a link (invalid for HTML4 and XHTML):

```
<a>
    <div>
        <p>...</p>
        <img />
    </div>
</a>
```

In this case, Google Translator will remove the link from the structure.

Note: I haven't tried it with HTML5 doctype. HTML5 allows wrapping pretty much anything inside a link, therefore, Google Translator might not remove the link with HTML5 doctype.